# "Bought" versus "acquired"

Tags: meaning-in-context

A friend of mine used the following sentence:

> I recently acquired a pizza stone to use for baking bread.

In Italian, *comprare* (*buy*) and *acquistare* (*acquire*, in a sentence like the previous one) both imply that I paid for something. Is it so also for English?

The reason I am asking is that I noticed that *acquire* is also used in cases where Italian would use *acquisire*, which normally doesn't imply any payment. My doubt is that, in the example sentence I used, *acquire* could not necessarily mean something was paid, but it could also mean something was obtained in other ways. Is it really so?

Comment: Per @bytebuster's first MW definition, because *acquired* is a relatively "unusual" word, using it would very often imply that you "came by" the pizza stone via some non-standard route - for example, it [fell off the back of a lorry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fall_off_the_back_of_a_lorry), or your millionaire Italian aunt just died, but the only thing she left you in her will was that pizza stone you'd always admired whenever you visited her as a child.

Comment: That is what I was thinking. By the way, your comment seems a good answer. `:)` I like the examples you made.

Comment: I'm guessing you might be Italian, so I made up the Italian aunt specially for you! If she's actually *real*, you can always practice hard and get *really* good at stonebaked pizza - then open a global chain of "authentic" pizzerias, and soon you'll be even richer than your sibling who got left all the money!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Merriam-Webster [defines](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acquire) *acquire* as the following (highlight is mine):

> a. to come into possession or control of often **by unspecified means**;
>   b. to come to have as a new or added characteristic, trait, or ability (as by sustained effort or natural selection);

So, you are right: *acquire* does not necessarily mean something was really *bought*.

It should be noticed that *buy* is quite informal, so it may happen that someone wants to use a more formal word. I would use *purchase* in this case, however.

Comment: +1 An elegant marriage of authority and relevance. ... the less formal variant of *acquired* might be *got hold of* (or to be really informal, *got ahold of*).

Comment: I wouldn't be _too_ concerned about the alleged informality of _buy_. It's an [often-used word](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bought+a+house%2Cpurchased+a+house%2Cbought+a+car%2Cpurchased+a+car&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) that isn't likely to be perceived as too informal (at least, not in the U.S.).

Comment: @J.R. The NOAD says that _buy_ used as noun is informal ("the wine is a good buy at $3.49"). As verb, it is not said to be informal, except in _buy the farm_, which means something else than buying. Does this match with your _experience_? (I could not find a word to use instead of _experience_. `:)`)

Comment: I would buy that. (By the way, the verb _buy_ is also listed as informal, when it means "to believe", as in, _"I'm not sure I buy that explanation."_) But _"I'm going to buy a pizza stone for my brother"_ would be fine; if anything, _purchase_ might sound overly formal in a context like that.